# Python - Getting SyntaxWarnings - how do i stop them?

Tags: python

I keep on getting this warning:

```
    Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\finlx\Desktop\file.py", line 49
    global m
SyntaxWarning: name 'm' is assigned to before global declaration
```

I have looked through the code, the program works perfectly but it gives me about 10 of those warnings (each for the same problem but a different variable) is there either a way to disable this or am i typing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have something like `def foo(): m = 4; global m`? If so the `global m` should come before the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have something like this:

```
>> m = 10
>> def foo():
    m = 55
    global m

<stdin>:3: SyntaxWarning: name 'm' is assigned to before global declaration
>> foo()
>> m
55
```

If so, simply put the `global m` declaration first:

```
>> m = 10
>> def foo():
    global m
    m = 55
>> foo()
>> m
55
```

Answer (score 0):

Claudiu's answer is correct as to what *you* should do: move your global statement.

Even though Python works with `global` anywhere in a function, I believe experience showed that 'out of order' code was sometimes buggy, due to someone thinking that the order is significant. When a change was made, it was decided to avoid breaking existing correctly working code by raising SyntaxError and warn with SyntaxWarning instead.

If one imports code that one cannot fix, the warning can be suppressed at the command line.  I believe "-W ignore::SyntaxWarning" would be the appropriate incantation, but I have not tested.  One can wrap an import as follows.

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore', SyntaxWarning)
    # simulate import of module giving SyntaxWarning
    warnings.warn('bad', SyntaxWarning)
```

No warning is printed. Comment out the simplefilter line and one is.